# Android Overflow Button custom icon not working for APIs < 5.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-appcompat

I am setting custom overflow icon in compat theme like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/action_bar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/status_bar</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/theme_red</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowMenuButton</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/theme_red</item>
</style>

<style name="OverflowMenuButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_overflow</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I get the following (desired and correct) result on Nexus 5 API 5.1:
[image]

However when I test the same app on API 4.4.4 or 4.2.2 (tested on Nexus 4, Xperia Z etc.), in both cases, I don't get the custom overflow icon. Here's the screenshot:
[image]

I am using toolbar from appcompat library v7:21, but I don't think the issue is due to toolbar. What am I doing wrong here?

As a follow up question, I will be happy to just change the color of overflow icon while keeping the same shape. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Have you tried simply adding a non-Android prefixed `<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowMenuButton</item>` to your theme?

Comment: No I didn't, now I have and it works. :) 
You can add an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per earlier comment: it looks like you forgot to add the non-Android-prefixed version of `actionOverflowButtonStyle` to your theme. Add the following:

```
<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowMenuButton</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to remove the following line

```
<item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowMenuButton</item>
```

then add the below code

```
<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowMenuButton</item>
```

it will work